# Batch script to pick filename from a text file and find the latest file

Tags: batch-file, file-search

Scenario:
We have multiple releases of a product, and for each release, a folder is created in the main folder. A help file is modified in various releases. I have all the help file names listed in a text file.
I need a script to:

1. Take each file name from the filenames.txt file
2. Search for the file by that name in the entire directory (in all releases)
3. Find the latest file
4. Copy it to a specified folder

I took help from the various pieces of code I found on Stack Overflow, and combined them to get this code:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
echo.
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("filenames.txt") do (
      SET "x=%%a"
      ECHO '!x!'
      SET FFPath=C:\SVN\nlbavwdocsvn\rep_doc_erpln\trunk\ERPLN
      SET NewPath=C:\Lavanya\extracted
      SET NewestDate=20160824
      ECHO Recursively searching %FFPath%
      FOR /F %%I in ('DIR %FFPath%\ !x! /a:-d /s /b') DO (
          SET FullDate=%%~tI
          ECHO %FFPath%
          REM Set CurrDate to yyyymmdd format.  Note:  Will fail if regional settings changed.
          SET CurrDate=!FullDate:~6,4!!FullDate:~0,2!!FullDate:~3,2!

          If !CurrDate! gtr !NewestDate! (
              SET NewestDate=!CurrDate!
              SET NewestFile=%%~fI )
          ECHO Copying %NewestFile% to %NewPath%
          ECHO.
          COPY /Y "%NewestFile%" "%NewPath%"
          ECHO. 
      )
)
PAUSE
```

This code is not working. And I am unable to figure out the error.

Comment: you should replace `DIR %FFPath%\ !x!` with `DIR "%FFPath%\!x!"`. `dir` does search for multiple masks if delimted with a space (example: `dir *.txt *.jpg` will show all *.txt files and all *.jpg files)

Comment: Use delayed expansion for _all_ variables that are set _and_ read within the loops! And why not simply letting `dir` sort by date (`/o:d`)...

Comment: @Stephan I tried the change that you suggested, but it did not get me the expected results. Any other way of finding a solution? Thanks for taking time to look into the query!

Comment: @aschipfl I am not allowed to modify the structure of the directory. Can you please elaborate your suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: pull the copy out of the for loop!

Comment: @Stephan, can the required output be achieved using two separate batch files and call one from another.
Say, file1.bat reads one file name from the filenames.txt file, and then calls the file2.bat which takes this file name, runs this search and copies the latest file to the specified directory.
Is this an easy way to achieve the required output and is this possible?

Comment: Forget my `dir /o:d` idea; I did not recognise that you are searching recursively, and `dir /s /o:d` does not sort the entire list by date, but for each directory in the tree individually; sorry for that!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script to search for the most recently modified file, using the `wmic` command to retrieve the last modification date/time in a locale-independent manner (e. g., `20160824115500.000000+060`).

So for every file name read from the list file `.\filenames.txt`, the directory tree routed at directory `C:\SVN\nlbavwdocsvn\rep_doc_erpln\trunk\ERPLN` is searched for matching files recursively, and the respective modify date/time stamp is gathered. Due to its format, a simple greater-than (`GTR`) comparison can be done do determine whether or not it is a later point of time than a cached one; if the criterion is fulfilled, the cache is updated accordingly.

The upper-case `REM` and `ECHO` commands constitute placeholders only for the real action to be performed on the files. Extend the script there as you like. Variable `!LASTFILE!` holds the full path to each encountered file.

So here is the code:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "LOCATION=C:\SVN\nlbavwdocsvn\rep_doc_erpln\trunk\ERPLN"
set "FILELIST=.\filenames.txt"
set "WMICPROP=LastModified" & rem // {CreationDate | LastAccessed | LastModified}

pushd "%LOCATION%" || exit /B 1
for /F "usebackq eol=| delims=" %%L in ("%FILELIST%") do (
    set "LASTFILE="
    set "LASTFAGE=00000000000000.000000+000"
    for /F "eol=| delims=" %%F in ('dir /B /S /A:-D "%%~L"') do (
        set "FILE=%%F"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        set "FILE=!FILE:\=\\!"
        for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%J in ('
            2^> nul wmic DataFile WHERE ^(Name^="!FILE!"^) GET %WMICPROP% /VALUE ^|^| ^
                2^> nul wmic DataFile WHERE Name^="!FILE!" GET %WMICPROP% /VALUE
        ') do for /F %%I in ("%%J") do (
            endlocal
            set "FAGE=%%I"
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            if !FAGE! GTR !LASTFAGE! (
                endlocal
                set "LASTFILE=%%F"
                set "LASTFAGE=%%I"
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            )
        )
        endlocal
    )
    if defined LASTFILE (
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

        REM Do whatever you want with the file here...
        ECHO Newest file: "!LASTFILE!"

        endlocal
    )
)
popd

endlocal
exit /B
```

Comment: I used this code exactly same. I saved the code in test3.bat file, in the same location where the filenames.txt file is placed. When I double-clicked the file, the command-prompt window did not open. So I navigated to the folder using 'cd' command in the cmd window and run the test3.bat file. Got an error stating "The system cannot find the file .\filenames.txt". 
:-(

The file names in the filenames.txt file look like this:
        tsacm0100m000
        tsacm0110m000
        tsacm0410m000
        tsacm1101m000

987 such lines are available in the file.

Comment: If `filenames.txt` is at the same location as the batch file, replace `set "FILELIST=.\filenames.txt"` by `set "FILELIST=%~dp0filenames.txt"`...